# How to filter HTML menu by a specific value in the json I am retrieving the content from, using plain JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm trying to create a menu list of questions that I retrieve from a database, but with being able to filter the questions by their type and their difficulty (easy/medium/hard). So for example, if I filter by difficulty "hard", and question type "for loop", it will only list questions who's JSON values satisfy those.

I have no problem creating an html menu and displaying all the questions from my JSONs, but I am having trouble implementing this filter system. 
Here's a sample of the JSON objects I get back from my database request

```
{
"questions": [
    {
        "questionId": "1",
        "questionText": "Create a function named \"add\" that adds 2 parameters",
        "testCase": "3,5",
        "expectedReturn": "8"
        "difficulty":"hard"
        "type":"general"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "12",
        "questionText": "Write a function named \"subtract\" that takes two integers, and subtracts the second from the first.",
        "testCase": "10,3",
        "expectedReturn": "7"
        "difficulty":"medium"
        "type":"math"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "88",
        "questionText": "Write a function named \"reverse\" that takes one parameter, a string t, and returns the string backwards.",
        "testCase": "hello",
        "expectedReturn": "olleh"
        "difficulty":"easy"
        "type":"string"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "89",
        "questionText": "Write a function called \"greeting\" that takes in one string parameter, name, and returns the string \"Hello \" followed by the name.",
        "testCase": "Bob",
        "expectedReturn": "Hello Bob"
        "difficulty":"hard"
        "type":"for loop"   //doesn't make sense, but just as an example
    },
    {
        "questionId": "90",
        "questionText": "Write a function named isEvenOrOdd that takes in an integer n, and returns \"even\" if it is even, and \"odd\" if it is odd.",
        "testCase": "12",
        "expectedReturn": "even"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "93",
        "questionText": "Write a function named \"addFiveDivideFive\" that takes in 5 integer parameters, adds them all together, and divides the sum by 5. Return this quotient.",
        "testCase": "10,5,15,25,35,50",
        "expectedReturn": "28"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "94",
        "questionText": "Write a function called findLength that takes in a string parameter t, and returns the length of that string.",
        "testCase": "helloworld",
        "expectedReturn": "10"
         "difficulty":"easy"
         "type":"general"
    },
    {
        "questionId": "95",
        "questionText": "Write a function named multiply that takes in two integers, and returns the product",
        "testCase": "3,5",
        "expectedReturn": "15"
        "difficulty":"hard"
        "type":"math"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Do you know about the array `.filter()` method? It's easy to filter the array, but hard to say how that would fit into your html generating code when you haven't shown that part.

Comment: what should happen with non specified type/difficulty?

Comment: _"but I am having trouble implementing this filter system"_ - then show us what you tried. Please go read [ask]. That you show us what you tried, explain your reasoning behind it and how it fails to achieve what you want, are kinda the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your question by using the word `filter`

try this :

```
var filterValue = 'easy'
var filteredMenu = yourObject.questions.filter(function(q) {
  return q.difficulty === filterValue
})

console.log(filteredMenu)
```

or the ES6 version

```
const filterValue = 'easy'
const filteredMenu = yourObject.questions.filter(q => q.difficulty === filterValue)

console.log(filteredMenu)
```